# How to reformat JSON via a struct?

Tags: json, go

I have pulled some data out of a given database - the format however is not correct as per what I want.

Sample struct:

```
type myStruct struct {
    ID                  int    `json:"Id"`
    Language            string `json:"Language"`
    Location            string `json:"Location"`
}
```

Right, I serialize a given map of strings with a custom struct representing the given returned columns:

```
func transformJSON(extract []map[string]*sql.SqlCell) ([]byte, error) {
    return json.MarshalIndent(extract, "", " ")
}
```

This returns valid JSON, but with the format:

```
  {
      {
      "id": {
       "Value": {
        "Long": 12353
       }
      },
      "language": {
       "Value": {
        "String_": "ja-JP"
       }
      },
      "location": {
       "Value": {
        "String_": "Osaka"
       }
  },
```

Referring to my struct above, I'd like a format as such:

```
 [
  {
    "Id": 12353,
    "Language": "ja-JP",
    "Location": "Osaka"
  },
  // .. other objects
 ]
```

Assuming the same input to the `func transformJSON`, how would I match the nested keys with the column type values as well?

Should I `Marshal` the map first, then transform the data -- or work directly with the `[]map[string]*sql.SqlCell` data structure before marshal?

In my head, I was thinking along the lines of:

```
func transformJSON(extract []map[string]*sql.SqlCell) ([]byte, error) {
    struct :=[] myStruct{}
    // Loop over extract objects, match nested keys, write to struct?

    return json.MarshalIndent(struct, "", " ")
}
```

Comment: To summarize, your question is: How to unmarshal `{"Id":{"Value":...}}` into your provided struct? Is that it?

Comment: @Flimzy `{"Id":{"Value":...}}` and the value of the key after - f.e. `"String_ "` or  `"Long"` :) It's double nested. So more like unmarshaling `{"Id":{"Value":{"String_": <Value>}}`, as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom unmarshaler, that unmarshals the entire thing, then converts for you:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    ID                  int    `json:"Id"`
    Language            string `json:"Language"`
    Location            string `json:"Location"`
}

type val struct {
    Value struct {
        String string `json:"String_"`
        Long   int    `json:"Long"`
    }
}

func (s *MyStruct) UnmarshalJSON(p []byte) error {
    var result struct{
        ID       val `json:"Id"`
        Language val `json:"language"`
        Location val `json:"location"`
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(p, &result); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    s.ID = result.ID.Value.Long
    s.Language = result.Langauge.Value.String
    s.Location= result.Location.Value.String
    return nil
}
```

Note that minimal error checking and data validation is done in this example--I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Trying it out -- however for example at `result.ID.Long` I get `Undefined`  since the `val` struct doesn't have it -- I see where you're going with this and trying to work with it, but perhaps you can elaborate? Cheers..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... where are you getting  "Undefined"?  And the `val` struct does have a `Long` field...

Comment: Running it throws: `\main.go:107:18: result.ID undefined (type map[string]struct...`

Comment: Oh I see. I've corrected the code... (I started with a map, converted to struct, and failed to do a full conversion)

Comment: Ah good, that threw me off a bit. Thanks. I'm unsure of how to exactly use the `UnmarshalJSON` function in my case, though it looks like the right direction. Digging into it, thanks for the help.

Comment: With `UnmarshalJSON` in place, you can just unmarshal your data structure as normal. To unmarshal an list of your custom types, for instance:  `x := []*MyStruct{}; json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &x)`

Comment: Gotcha. Right now, it prints the objects as I wish, however the values are empty strings(except ID, which defaults to 0). Hmm. Gotta debug it. Thanks for your advice though :)! Doesn't your way call the standard json.Unmarshal, though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179749/discussion-between-cbll-and-flimzy).

Comment: @cbll: I see you found the solution. I'm glad to hear that!

Comment: indeed - thanks for your help, I learned a thing or two about structs+json in Go. Edited your answer to represent my end-solution.